# Rails: Check if instance is valid without checking if associations are valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

We have a `Zoo` model that has_many `Animal`s:

```
  has_many(
    :animals,
    validate: false,
  )
```

I want to check if a `Zoo` is valid inside a controller, but inside this controller I do not want to check if the associated `Animal` objects are valid.

In all other contexts I want to validate if the associated `Animal`s are valid.

How can we check that just this `Zoo` is valid?

Comment: Is there a `validates_associated :animals` statement on your Zoo model?

Comment: negative, but in case it's relevant, an `Animal` `belongs_to` `AnimalKeeper`, and we do have a `has_many :animal_keepers, through: :animals` in the `Zoo` model

Comment: `belongs_to` has a default presence check unless you make it optional. So if you have a belongs_to on Zoo, you may need to add `optional: true` to the association statement. If that's not it, it would be helpful to see what the error looks like. You could call `zoo.valid?` then `zoo.errors.full_messages`.

Comment: What's the problem with simple `zoo.valid?` ?

Comment: It appears that checking `zoo.valid?` is running the validations on associations. A related bug seems to have been observed by others: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25718

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing the context to valid method?
eg:-

```rb
zoo.valid?(:create)
```